# Extract row from struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures, struct

I'm doing some image processing and I have to manipulate the result from **houghlines()**  and connect some lines manually.

The following *houghlines()* -result is given *(I shortened the entries of point1 and point2 to keep it clear)*:

```
lines(1) = struct('theta', 69, 'rho', 14);
lines(2) = struct('theta', 70, 'rho', 32);
lines(3) = struct('theta', 69, 'rho', 14);
lines(4) = struct('theta', 69, 'rho', 20);
lines(5) = struct('theta', 70, 'rho', 32);
```

Now, if the values of theta and rho are equal i would like to extract the specific rows so  i can later connect the Houghlines manually. 
The Result should be the corresponding rows of the lines structure. Like this:

```
A = [lines(1) lines(3)];
B = [lines(2) lines(5)];
C = [lines(4)];
```

I can not address things explicitly like in the above code, because **houglines()** is applied to a video. That means that the values  of *theta*, *rho* and even the length of *lines* is different for every frame.
So this must be evaluated dynamically.

I found out that with **nestedStruct()** from FileExchange i could sort my struct first by theta and then by rho. At this Point i am unable to disassemble the struct because i don't know how many elements i have to take for the resulting structures.
I also experimented with **unique()** an indexing but with no luck.

I hope that someone could give me a hint how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
% sample 1x5 structure array
clear lines
lines(1) = struct('theta', 69, 'rho', 14);
lines(2) = struct('theta', 70, 'rho', 32);
lines(3) = struct('theta', 69, 'rho', 14);
lines(4) = struct('theta', 69, 'rho', 20);
lines(5) = struct('theta', 70, 'rho', 32);

% build a two-columns matrix of theta/rho values
t = [lines.theta];
r = [lines.rho];
rows = [t(:) r(:)];

% find unique rows. ind will be an array of indices
% (ranging from 1 to number of unique rows)
[~,~,ind] = unique(rows, 'rows');
for i=1:max(ind)
    % indices of structs with equal theta/rho values
    idx = find(ind == i)

    % extract those structs and do something useful with them
    s = lines(idx);
    % ...
end
```

In the above example, the grouped indices found were:

```
idx =
     1
     3
idx =
     4
idx =
     2
     5
```

corresponding to the three groups of unique lines (`A`, `B`, `C` in your question).